# Dynamically add element in JS to XUL

Tags: javascript

When I run following code to display result for multiple USN(University Seat Number), it will display all at once when the result for all usn is loaded..
What I need is to display the result for each usn as soon as it is downloaded and send next request with next USN.

Here **loadResult(usnList[u])** function will send request to external University site..

```
for(var u=0; u<usnList.length; u++)
    {
        listitem = document.createElement("listitem");  
        listcell1 = document.createElement("listcell");
        listcell2 = document.createElement("listcell");
        listcell1.setAttribute("label", usnList[u]);
        listcell2.setAttribute("label", "Loading");
        listcell2.setAttribute("id", "id"+usnList[u]);
        listcell2.setAttribute("label", status);
        status=loadResult(usnList[u]);//Load result with one USN
        listitem.appendChild(listcell1);
        listitem.appendChild(listcell2);
        listbox.appendChild(listitem);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple, I fixed this problem..
What i did is that, instead of returning the status result from loadResult function, I display it in same function by using the element-ID..